# scheduling algorithm for running tasks at specified time

Tags: java

please suggest me best algo for the below situation:

I have some taks which are to be scheduled by users anytime, the tasks may have recurring options(periodically/weekly/monthly...).I have to run these tasks at the scheduled time.

1. Run only once after a specified start date
2. Run periodically for every 1 hour after a specified date
3. Run every week monday and tuesday for every i hr after a specified date
4. Run monthly at a particular date after a specified date.

Its better if you give the code snippet ...

Comment: I think you want a library or a service, not an algorithm.  It would be a lot of work (and a waste of time) to code a job scheduler "algorithm" yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a scheduler like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) or [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/) (pretty decent library and more lightweight than Quartz).

Answer (score 2):

The [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) integration server does exactly the same (in Java). It even implements the cron syntax allowing complex schedules. And it's [open source](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Source+code).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/overview/features.html) if you want a Java solution.  That link points to the Quartz features page, which looks like it could be a good fit to your requirements.  A stack of examples may be found [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/examples/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Quartz](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/;jsessionid=LDKHONNCOPJC) is a nice, open, extendable, Java based library.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not mandatory that you use Java for this, you should just use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). This is what cron is *for*.